# Property is coming up empty when called from another class when using URLSession

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

For some reason, the products array is coming back empty when I try and access it from another class. What am I doing wrong, and how can I get the products array to populate? Is it something related to the do/catch?

The print statement shown will give me what I'm looking for, but when I try and use the property in another class after the retrieve method has been called, it comes up empty.

For information, "Product" is a struct that has name, description, etc properties attached.

```
private let productListUrl = URL(string: "https://api/products.json")
var products = [Product]()

func retrieveProductList() {
    if let productListUrl = productListUrl {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: productListUrl) { (data, response, error) in
            if let data = data {
                do {
                    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String:Any]
                    let tempArray: Array = jsonData["products"] as! [Any]
                    for product in tempArray {
                        let newProduct = Product(json: product as! [String : Any])
                        self.products.append(newProduct!)
                    }
                    print("In ProductService: \(self.products)")
                }
                catch {
                    print("An error occured while attempting to read data")
                }
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: The products are being loaded in the background. They are not available until `print("In ProductService: \(self.products)")` is called.

Answer (score 0):

As maddy noted, this is because the URL call is asynchronous.

You basically have 3 options:

1. Use a semaphore approach and make your retrieveProductList method synchronous.
2. Change your class to have a delegate property that you can ping when the URL request finishes.
3. Add a completion handler to your retrieveProductList method that is called when the URL request finishes.

I personally would lean towards option 3:

```
func retrieveProductList(completion: @escaping ([Product])->())
{
    // Right after you print the products...
    completion(self.products)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the completion handler was the way I went, and it worked perfectly!